# Reflecting Return Date & Extension Date in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am setting up a Excel for Rental of Vehicle to Keep track of Vehicle Return Date & Extension Date. I can get the table to show vehicle return but couldnt get it to show the extension date.

Tried to use Multiple If And statement.

```
=IF(AND($B10<>"",$C10<>""),1-SUMPRODUCT(('[Rental Current Fleet.xlsm]Rental Vehicle'!$G$7:$G$1000<=H$7)*('[Rental Current Fleet.xlsm]Rental Vehicle'!$H$7:$H$1000>=H$7)*('[Rental Current Fleet.xlsm]Rental Vehicle'!$C$7:$C$1000=$B10)*('[Rental Current Fleet.xlsm]Rental Vehicle'!$D$7:$D$1000=$C10)),"")
```

**Above code is working

```
=IF(AND($B10<>"",$C10<>""),1-SUMPRODUCT(('[Rental Current Fleet.xlsm]Rental Vehicle'!$H$7:$H$1000<=H$7)*('[Rental Current Fleet.xlsm]Rental Vehicle'!$J$7:$J$1000>=H$7)*('[Rental Current Fleet.xlsm]Rental Vehicle'!$C$7:$C$1000=$B10)*('[Rental Current Fleet.xlsm]Rental Vehicle'!$D$7:$D$1000=$C10)),"")
```

Cell Shows #Value!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a more simpler approach:

[image]

Formula C2:

```
=A2+B2
```

Formula E2:

```
=D2-C2
```

Tips for total amount due:

[image]

Formula F2:

`=B2*VLOOKUP("Normal",$I$2:$J$3,2,FALSE)+E2*VLOOKUP("Extension",$I$2:$J$3,2,FALSE)`

Comment: @Twb Victor in the edited answer you could see a tip on how you may charge.

Answer (score 0):

[Vehicle Rental Availability](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzuk3.jpg)

I am actually trying to create an excel to indicate

1. Yellow - Vehicle Available
2. Grey - Vehicle Date out to Expected In Date
3. Blue - Vehicle Extended Date

[Input Fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKfQ8.jpg)